# More help on 2D array of playing cards C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I worked on my program more after asking for help once and this is what I have now.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
const int ROWS = 4;
string suits[ROWS] = 
{
    "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades"
};

const int COLS = 13;
string faces[COLS] = 
{
        "Ace", "Deuce", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
    "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"
};

int deck[ROWS][COLS] =
{
    {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13},
    {14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26},
    {27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39},
    {40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52}
};

for(int iii = 0; iii < ROWS; iii++)
{
    for(int jjj = 0; jjj < COLS; jjj++)
    {

        cout << deck[iii][jjj] << " " << faces[jjj] << " of " << suits[iii] << endl;
    }
}

srand((unsigned) time(0));

for(int c = 0; c < ROWS; c++)
{
    for(int d = 0; d < COLS; d++)
    {
        int face = rand() % 13;
        int suit = rand() % 4;

        cout << left << setw(5) << " " << faces[face] << " of " << suits[suit] << endl;
        int e = deck[suit][face];
        deck[suit][face] = deck[c][d];
        deck[c][d] = e;
        cout << deck[c][d];





    }
}
```

}

When I run the program the first loop simply lists the deck in order and works great:

```
1 Ace of Diamonds
2 Deuce of Diamonds
3 Three of Diamonds
4 Four of Diamonds
5 Five of Diamonds
6 Six of Diamonds
7 Seven of Diamonds
8 Eight of Diamonds
9 Nine of Diamonds
10 Ten of Diamonds
```

and so on. The second loop however is supposed to shuffle and print the deck again:

```
 Nine of Clubs
22     King of Hearts
39     Queen of Spades
51     Seven of Spades
46     Ace of Spades
40     Six of Spades
45     Three of Spades
42     Seven of Hearts
33     Four of Diamonds
46     Five of Diamonds
40     Seven of Diamonds
42     Queen of Clubs
25     Five of Clubs
18     Four of Hearts
30     Ace of Clubs
30     Three of Clubs
16     Jack of Clubs
24     Deuce of Spades
41     Eight of Diamonds
33     Queen of Spades
3     Seven of Hearts
8     Jack of Hearts
37     Eight of Diamonds
19     Four of Clubs
24     Queen of Hearts
38     Three of Hearts
29     Nine of Clubs
37     Ace of Diamonds
22     Ace of Hearts
37     Queen of Diamonds
25     Four of Diamonds
9     Four of Diamonds
31     Three of Hearts
37     Nine of Clubs
27     Nine of Clubs
34     Ten of Hearts
36     Five of Hearts
9     Jack of Clubs
24     Five of Spades
44     Seven of Clubs
3     Six of Hearts
31     Jack of Spades
50     Ten of Diamonds
40     Six of Clubs
33     Eight of Diamonds
23     Ten of Hearts
36     Ace of Hearts
26     Six of Spades
23     Nine of Clubs
35     Seven of Clubs
5     Five of Hearts
1     Five of Diamonds
10Press any key to continue . . .
```

Problem 1: All of the numbers of the 2D array do not correspond correctly with the strings of the 1D arrays. Example, the Nine of Clubs is along side the number 22 which is correct and the numbers are correct until you get to number 1 which is alongside the three of clubs which is not correct and it all messes up from there.

Problem 2: The numbers and strings do not perfectly align, the strings started printing first so the strings number is down one and over one.

Problem 3: Some of the numbers and strings repeat which I do not want. How do I make sure that they don't repeat.

Comment: As for the alignment problems check the [`setw()` I/O stream manipulator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip). As for your 1st problem note that indexing in c++ starts at `0`, not at `1`! You should have `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12}` for your 1st deck aso.

Comment: "more help" is not a question. And the problem stated in the post is too broad (not mentioning it's more than one problem). Please focus on one particular problem at time. It will not only help you get an answer on SO, but even solving the problems yourself.

Comment: Using a debugger is always more productive than using StackOverflow for finding your issues.

Answer (score 1):

The the reason you have problem number one is that your printout loop is broken.  Since you're using `iii` and `jjj` to index both `deck[][]` and the `faces[]` / `suits[]` pair, it'll only ever work right if the cards are all in sequence, as they are before the shuffle.

That said, if you think about it for a second, keeping the deck as a two dimensional array becomes pointless the moment you shuffle it.  Just maintain it as a one dimensional array of 52 cards.  Irrespective of that, number them from `0` to `51` inclusive, it'll save you a lot of pain and suffering in the long term.

To convert a card number back to a face and suit, you need to take the card number read from the `deck` array, evaluate `x / 13` to get an index into the `suit[]` array, and `x % 13` to get the index into the `faces[]` array.

Last but not least, your shuffle isn't quite perfect.  In practice, for a test program it'll be OK, but you should modify it to use the Fisher-Yates algorithm if you want to get serious.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle  It looks identical at first sight, but the modification to the parameter to the random number generator makes a difference.

Also steer clear of library provided `rand()`, it usually sucks.  I use an xor-shift RNG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift because it's good, as in sufficient for serious Monte-Carlo use, and blindingly fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the problem down into smaller pieces or steps, then run/debug them and see what the results are. Try putting cout statements (or debugging with breakpoints) at each step in the loop in question and print (or view in the debugger) the different variables involved. Go step by step to try to determine what is going wrong. Don't be afraid to write the execution steps of the loop out on paper. Sometimes errors can become very obvious after doing this.

How to debug is a crucial skill that all programmers must learn. If you cannot debug your code well then these issues will only get worse and even harder to solve as your programs get more complicated.